# ZF, ZFDoctrine and PHPUnit setup

Tags: unit-testing, zend-framework, doctrine, phpunit, zfdoctrine

Does anyone here use Zend Framework, [ZFDoctrine](http://github.com/beberlei/zf-doctrine) and PHPUnit together?

How to rebuild the database on each test run?
How to separate local/production/testing environments?

Would you share your unit testing setup?

I have been trying something like that:

```
// /tests/bootstrap.php
// ... setup paths and constants here
require_once 'Zend/Application.php';
// Create application, bootstrap, and run
$application = new Zend_Application(
    APPLICATION_ENV,
    APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/application.ini'
);

$application->bootstrap('doctrine');
$provider = new ZFDoctrine_Tool_DoctrineProvider;
$provider->generateModelsFromYaml();
//$provider->buildProject(true);
```

But this ends in:

```
Notice: Constant APPLICATION_PATH already defined in /home/user/www/library/ZendFramework/1.10.7/library/Zend/Tool/Project/Context/Zf/BootstrapFile.php on line 106

Fatal error: Call to a member function getResponse() on a non-object in /home/user/www/library/zf-doctrine/library/ZFDoctrine/Tool/DoctrineProvider.php on line 271
```

Models are not generated.

I get similar errors running:

```
$provider->createDatabase();
```

But in this case database is created.
The other provider commands do not work.

---

The solution:

```
$provider = new ZFDoctrine_Tool_DoctrineProvider;
$registry = new Zend_Tool_Framework_Registry;
$provider->setRegistry($registry);
@$provider->buildProject(true);
```

If anybody knows a better approach, please correct me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't used ZFDoctrine, but just plain Doctrine 1.2. I don't know if my solution is better but I figured I post if any1 is interested, here's the bootstrap.php in my tests folder:

```
<?php

// Define path to application directory
defined('APPLICATION_PATH')
    || define('APPLICATION_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../application'));

// Define application environment
/**
 * In the application.ini:
[testing : production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1
doctrine.dsn = "mysql://my_user:passwd@localhost/my_phpunit_test_db"
 */
define('APPLICATION_ENV', 'testing');

// Ensure library/ is on include_path
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
    realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../library'),
    get_include_path()
)));

/** Zend_Application */
require_once 'Zend/Application.php';

// Create application, bootstrap, and run
$application = new Zend_Application(
    APPLICATION_ENV,
    APPLICATION_PATH . '/../configs/application.ini'
);

$application->getBootstrap()->bootstrap();

// Can run out if too small
ini_set('memory_limit', '512M');

// Get the doctrine settings
$config = $application->getOption('doctrine');
$cli = new Doctrine_Cli($config);
$cli->run(array("doctrine", "build-all-reload","force"));
```

The key here is actually the last line that rebuilds all databases creating a clean environment for each testing.